# Gulp - Zip the contents of subfolders & name these archives after them

Tags: gulp, gulp-zip

I would like to use Gulp & gulp-zip to:

1. Zip each subfolder of `./lessons/` folder
2. Name each archive after the original folder name. So archived folder `./lessons/1-hermit-crab/` should be named `1-hermit-crab.zip`.
3. Move all these archives into the `./lessons/` folder.

I have started with this, but got stuck on not being able to retrieve the name of the ziped directory, so that I can use it for the archive name. So I keep the archives in the subfolder now.

Thanks for any help.

```
gulp.task('zip-lessons', function() {
    // Get an array of subdirectories under ./lessons/
    var subDirectories = glob.sync('./lessons/*/');
    // For each directory…
    subDirectories.forEach(function (subDirectory) {
        return gulp.src(subDirectory + '**')
            .pipe(zip('lesson.zip'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(subDirectory));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use node's `path` module to get the name of the subdirectory like so:

```
const path = require('path');
const dirName = path.parse('./folderA/folderB').base // -> 'folderB'
```

And pass the dirName to `zip()`:

```
const { task, src, dest } = require('gulp');
const path = require('path');
const zip = require('gulp-zip');
const glob = require('glob');

const subDirs = glob.sync('./lessons/*');

task('zipLessions', (done) => {
  subDirs.forEach(subDir => {
    const dirName = path.parse(subDir).base;
    src(subDir + '/*')
      .pipe(zip(`${dirName}.zip`))
      .pipe(dest('./lessons'))
  })
  done()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

My colleague has offered me this solution that works, so now I am using it.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const zip = require('gulp-zip');

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

// Functions

function getFolders(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir)
      .filter(function(file) {
        return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
      });
}

// Tasks

// Zip each folder in /lessons and place the archive in the /lessons root
gulp.task('zip-lessons', () => {
    let folders = getFolders('lessons/');
    console.log(folders)
    var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
      gulp.src(`lessons/${folder}/**`)
        .pipe(zip(`${folder}.zip`))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('lessons'))
    })
});
```